# Vuejs component click event not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuikit

I am using Vuejs - Vuikit components and have the following setup:

```
<template>
    <div class="uk-scope">
        <vk-modal :show="isShow" v-if="config">
          <vk-modal-close @click="alert('hello!')" large></vk-modal-close>
          <vk-notification :messages.sync="messages"></vk-notification>
            <app-breadcrumb :current-view="currentView" />
            <!-- render the currently active component/page here -->
            <component v-bind:is="currentView"/>
        </vk-modal>
    </div>
</template>
```

My issue is that, the close modal does not see to fire the `@click` function.

The parent component, does emit an event, but I would prefer to fire something directly from the close button.

I have tried to use `@click.native="someFunction()"`, but this has not helped!

Comment: Do you get any errors on the console? If I'm understanding correctly, the `alert('hello!')` is supposed to display when the dialog closes? If that's the case it might be that when it closes, you lose the reference to that method, so it never occurs

Answer (score 0):

Hey I've not used vuikit before but from their documents they show this is how to close a modal. I would also remove that v-if="config" as that might be confusing Vue

```
<template>
    <div class="uk-scope">
        <vk-modal :show.sync="isShow">
          <vk-modal-close @click="isShow = false" large></vk-modal-close>
          <vk-notification :messages.sync="messages"></vk-notification>
            <app-breadcrumb :current-view="currentView" />
            <!-- render the currently active component/page here -->
            <component v-bind:is="currentView"/>
        </vk-modal>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `@click.native="someFunction"` note that this does not have `()`.